EDIT : Excel( or Python) Formula to Recursively List All Ingredients and Sub-Ingredients of a Recipe
EDIT: The problem has already been resolved elegantly, one could say, using recursive Lambda. However, since Python has become available in Excel, I have begun learning Python and taking courses. Yet, for this particular problem, I am currently unable to find a way to accomplish the task using Python in Excel. I want to find out if Python is as strong as people say :), could anyone provide assistance pls 
?
I need help with creating an Excel formula that can handle a specific task related to recipes. Here’s the situation:
I have a list of recipes, and each recipe contains a list of ingredients. Some of these ingredients are themselves recipes with their own lists of ingredients (sub-ingredients). I want to create a formula that can take a single ingredient as input and return a complete list of all the ingredients needed, including any sub-ingredients, recursively.
For example, if I have the following data:
Recipe A: Ingredient 1, Ingredient 2, Ingredient 3
Ingredient 1: Sub-ingredient 1.1, Sub-ingredient 1.2
Ingredient 2: Sub-ingredient 2.1, Sub-ingredient 2.2
Sub-ingredient 1.1: Sub-sub-ingredient 1.1.1, Sub-sub-ingredient 1.1.2
If I input "Recipe A", I want to get a list that includes:
Ingredient 1

Sub-ingredient 1.1

Sub-sub-ingredient 1.1.1
Sub-sub-ingredient 1.1.2


Sub-ingredient 1.2

Ingredient 2

Sub-ingredient 2.1

Sub-sub-ingredient 2.1.1


Sub-ingredient 2.2

Ingredient 3
The formula should continue to expand any sub-ingredients until there are no more nested ingredients left.
I would appreciate any guidance or examples of how to achieve this in Excel. Ideally, I’m looking for a solution that doesn’t require VBA, but I’m open to all suggestions.
I have Excel 365, and I was trying to find a solution with the BYROW function, but it doesn't stack arrays.
Thanks in advance for your help!
I have Excel 365, and I was trying to find a solution with the BYROW function, but it doesn't stack arrays.
i thought about recursive lambda, but I'm stuck, my initial table is disposed like this



Recipe Name
Ingredient 1
Quantity 1
Ingredient 2
Quantity 2
Ingredient 3
Quantity 3




Recipe A
Ingr 1
2
Ingr 2
3
Ingr 3
1


Ingr 1
Sub Ingr 1
4
Sub Ingr 2
5
Sub Ingr 3
5


Sub Ingr 1
Sub Sub Ingr 1.1
3







Now, I am attempting a different method to present the data, which may simplify achieving the desired outcome, or not ... :) (refer to the following):



Recipe Name
Ingredient
Quantity




Recipe A
Ingr 1
2


Recipe A
Ingr 2
3


Recipe A
Ingr 3
1


Ingr 1
Sub  Ingr 1
4


Ingr 1
Sub  Ingr 2
5


Ingr 1
Sub  Ingr 3
5


Sub Ingr 1
Sub Sub Ingr 1.1
3



EDIT: The Desired outcome if I'm looking for Recipe A for exemple is something like:



Ingredient
Quantity




Ingr 1
2


Ingr 2
3


Ingr 3
1


Sub  Ingr 1
8


Sub  Ingr 2
10


Sub  Ingr 3
10


Sub Sub Ingr 1.1
24



Since RECIPE A requires 2 quantities of Ingredient 1, all sub-ingredients of Ingredient 1 should be multiplied accordingly.

Sub ingr 1 = 4x2=8
Sub ingr 2 = 5x2=10
Sub ingr 3 = 5x2=10
Sub Sub Ingr 1.1 = 3x8=24 ( ingr1 contain 3 Sub Sub Ingr 1.1 , since Sub Ingr 1 is now 8 in quantity Sub Sub Ingredient 1.1 = base value x qty of ingr 1 = 3x8=24 )


I will put this into the mix as well. Similar to @Rachel's I guess, I have also used the advanced formula environment to define a recursive formula like this:
=LET(
    subList, FILTER(TAKE(List, , -2), TAKE(List, , 1) = Parent, ""),
    IF(
        @subList = "",
        {"", ""},
        DROP(
            REDUCE(
                {"", ""},
                SEQUENCE(ROWS(subList)),
                LAMBDA(a, c,
                    VSTACK(a, INDEX(subList, c, 0), FindIngredients(INDEX(subList, c, 1), List))
                )
            ),
            1
        )
    )
)

called as:
=FindIngredients(Parent,List)


The blank rows can be filtered out and the order changed but these are time-consuming to debug so enough for now.
Also I have only just read the comments about cascading the ingredient amounts down to sub ingredients - food for thought (literally).

Here is my version of the cascaded ingredients formula:
=LET(
    subList, FILTER(TAKE(List, , -2), TAKE(List, , 1) = Parent, ""),
    IF(
        @subList = "",
        {"", ""},
        DROP(
            REDUCE(
                {"", ""},
                SEQUENCE(ROWS(subList)),
                LAMBDA(a, c,
                    LET(
                        m, Multiplier * INDEX(subList, c, 2),
                        VSTACK(
                            a,
                            HSTACK(INDEX(subList, c, 1), m),
                            CascadeIngredients(INDEX(subList, c, 1), m, List)
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            1
        )
    )
)

Called as:
CascadeIngredients(Parent,Multiplier,List)



That is actually impressive; you and Rachel seem to have found a good approach to this problem. I need a bit of free time to process this. The second method of organizing the data in a table appears easier to collate the desired information for each recipe. Rachel used the table format: one line per recipe with multiple columns versus one line per ingredient of a specific recipe/ingredient. And Yes, cascading the ingredient amount was not in the original thread since i though it was too hard ,but  Rachel seem to found a way through (i will check how exactly later)  :) Thank you both of you <3

I am completely astounded by what I have seen and learned today. I'm very grateful. Although I'm still a novice with "recursive lambda," I'm truly impressed. I managed to achieve the needed result today, but solely via a complex formula, multiple helper's columns, and repeating the same thing 40 times in one formula to ensure sufficient recursion... Then you came along and elegantly condensed it all, overcoming my challenges with merely 10 lines of code.... thank you very much Tom and @Rachel you made my day <3 <3

Lets give a try to the following formula-
=HSTACK(INDEX(A2:A5,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE((COLUMNS(B2:G5)/2)*(ROWS(A2:A5)))/(COLUMNS(B2:G5)/2),0)),
WRAPROWS(TOROW(B2:G5),2))

Another approach could be-
=LET(
rcp,DROP(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(TEXTJOIN("|",1,A2:A5)&"|",COLUMNS(B2:G2)/2),"|")),-1),
wrp,WRAPROWS(TOROW(B2:G5),2),
HSTACK(rcp,wrp)
)



It's interesting , unfortunately, I don't have access to WRAPROWS, and I'm not sure why... Regarding the desired outcome, I'm looking for a way to display, for example, when you search for RECIPE A, all the ingredients (Ingr 1, Ingr 2, Ingr 3) and all the sub-ingredients (Sub Ingredient 1, Sub Ingredient 2, Sub Ingredient 3, Sub Ingredient 4) in one column, with the corresponding quantities in a second column. I'm not certain if this is feasible....

Upon rereading my question, I realize it may have caused some misunderstanding regarding the result I was seeking. I described two methods of displaying the data; however, the second table is not the desired outcome. It is actually another way to present the data, perhaps making it easier to process towards the desired result. I have edited the post to clarify, apologies for any confusion.

What is exactly your excel version? how come you have BYROW but not WRAPROWS?

If you want to use recursive lambda, you better specify ingredients for each recipe or parent ingredients like this: https://imgur.com/a/o4p1iUk . ie. Recipe A is made up of Ingr1, Ingr2, Ingr3. then Ingr1 is made up of Ingr4, Ingr5, Ingr6; Ingr2 is made up of Ingr4; Ingr 3, 4, 5, 6 has no child ingredients... using this table and recursive function, we can work out the lowest level of ingredients Recipe A needs....if that is not what you need, then I think Harun's answer makes sense.. WRAPROWS is the easiest way to reshape table.

@Rachel I conducted my research (I have the French version), and the translation I found online for WRAPROWS in French was ENVLIGNES. However, when you mentioned it, i did my own research in all excel function i have, and I discovered ORGA.LIGNES (which is WRAPROWS) ..... So, it turns out I do have this function but wasn't aware of it. It makes me wonder what other functions I might have that I don't know about....

Congratulations on your new findings!

@rachel Regarding the solution, there may be aspects that I'm not fully understanding. It appears not to search for the recipe but rather takes an array and reshapes it. My data table contains all recipes, sub-recipes, and ingredients, although not all are interconnected. What I aim to create is a lookup function that, given the "Name of the recipe," retrieves all associated sub-recipes, ingredients, and sub-ingredients.

@rachel, I can retrieve an array of ingredients for a single recipe, but I aim to replicate this process for each ingredient to obtain its sub-ingredients, continuing recursively until there are no more sub-ingredients, and then vertically stack all the data. This is why I considered a recursive approach. I'm not sure if it's feasible, though—to start with one element, generate an array, then search for each element within this new array to gather more data and stack them.

I see, I was trying to decide whether recursive lookup is really necessary. From what you describe, it seems so. Also, I saw Recipe A has Ingr1 with Qty = 2, should Sub Ingredients of Ingr1's quantity also  be multiplied by 2?

This is exactly what I was looking for, but I didn't mention it at first to avoid complications. If recipe A has 2 units of ingredient 1, then each unit of ingredient 1 should be multiplied accordingly. Moreover, if ingredient 1 includes sub-ingredients 1 and 2, their quantities should also be adjusted based on the new amount of ingredient 1, and so forth. My brain is overwhelmed trying to find a solution, and I'm not even certain it's feasible.

OK, Finally worked it out.
Data put in range A1:G6.

Named range:
Parents
=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5
Children
=Sheet1!$B$2:$G$5

First customised function:
GetSubIngredientsAndQtys
=LET(
    wrapped, WRAPROWS(TOROW(ingredients_and_qtys, 3), 2, ""),
    ingredients, TAKE(wrapped, , 1),
    qtys, TAKE(wrapped, , -1),
    numIngredients, ROWS(ingredients),
    stacked, REDUCE(
        "",
        SEQUENCE(numIngredients, 1, 1, 1),
        LAMBDA(a, i,
            LET(
                ingredient, INDEX(ingredients, i, 1),
                qty, INDEX(qtys, i, 1),
                sub_ingredients_and_qtys, XLOOKUP(ingredient, Parents, Children, "", 0, 1),
                IF(
                    sub_ingredients_and_qtys = "",
                    a,
                    LET(
                        sub_wrapped, WRAPROWS(sub_ingredients_and_qtys, 2, ""),
                        sub_ingredients, TAKE(sub_wrapped, , 1),
                        sub_qtys, TAKE(sub_wrapped, , -1),
                        VSTACK(a, TOROW(HSTACK(sub_ingredients, qty * sub_qtys)))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    IF(ROWS(stacked) = 1, "", TOROW(DROP(stacked, 1, 0), 3))
)


Then a recursive lambda(StackIngredients) that calls this GetSubIngredientsAndQtys:
=LET(
    sub_ingredients_and_qtys, GetSubIngredientsAndQtys(ingredients_and_qtys),
    IF(
        sub_ingredients_and_qtys = "",
        stacked,
        StackIngredients(sub_ingredients_and_qtys, VSTACK(stacked, sub_ingredients_and_qtys))
    )
)


Finally, using this recursive lambda to get the final output:
=WRAPROWS(TOROW(StackIngredients(B2:G2,B2:G2),3),2,"")


It seems like a good start; thank you for your efforts. I've been at this for two days and can't figure out a way. Perhaps, as mentioned in the original post, changing the way I arrange the data with fewer columns, or using a helper column, maybe ... I'm at a dead end and continue to research online. I'm surprised I haven't found an equivalent problem, as it seems very useful in many fields to be able to extract this type of connected hierarchical data.

I blame limitations in bloody MS365. first, most recursive functions can be replaced by a simple while loop in other programming languages. second, it still amazes me that 365 dynamic array doesn’t understand nested array….

Updated. Need to use both REDUCE and recursive lambda....

I've just saw your answer; sadly I'm at work and think I need to concentrate fully to process this, line by line... with plenty of coffee :) It's impressive, as I can see it yielded the desired result. I believe I will learn quite a bit from going through this. If you add another recipe that isn't RECIPE A (RECIPE B, with some ingredient shared with recipe A and other not ) , will you filter out the ingredients and substitute or need another data range for each recipe? I think I need to read and understand all your lines of code before asking such questions, sorry :))

Good luck! I put most logic in GetSubIngredientsAndQtys so recursive lambda would be simpler...hope that make things less painful...

thank you very much Rachel you and @Tom Sharpe made my day <3 <3, you are the best I'm totally satisfied with your answers.

Glad it helps. but it is literally the first time I heard someone saying recursive lambda make their day!

Haha, absolutely :D ! The struggle was real the past 2 days from this problem, but even though I'm still new to this, I've already learned so much!
